# How to Clone the sharepoint 2010 farm server

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to setup a clone Server for Sharepoint 2010

There are four production server running sharepoint server 2010 and one SQL server for ContentDB management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to replicate one of the production server in the farm and later sync the data between the production and data recovery server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend,1st update your question so no more down vote.

What I understand, you want build a single server farm as DR of your production.

1st you have to install sharepoint on new server (same build/version level as your prod).

Apply all the customization (solutions,  3rd party wsp, master pages), if any.

Configure all the service applications as you have in prod.

Create new web applications

Now take the content database backup using sql from prod and restore it on Dr farm sql server.

Now mount the database to appreciate Web application.

This will restore the production into DR farm.

But big question is, how you want sync the data, every day restore production db to DR?