# Create Clone of SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, clone

I have seen below post but our scenario is different thus asking it separately
[How to Clone the sharepoint 2010 farm server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103707/how-to-clone-the-sharepoint-2010-farm-server)

We have to create a clone of our existing SharePoint 2010 Farm. Our current farm is 3 tier. App Server and Web server are VMs and DB is on a another server (physical machine).
We have created Copies of App server and Web server VMs. Now what we should do next.

As per the above post we have to "take the content database backup using sql from prod and restore it on Dr farm sql server and mount the database to appropriate Web application."

What further steps to do...
Kindly suggest am quite new to sharepoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build new sharepoint server by fresh installation then

- backup the content db from existing farm
- restored it to ur clone farm db servers
- attach to web application
- test it

If your clone farm is in different domain then may be u have to run move-spuser command

Comment: Waqas, Thank you for the reply. We have created copy of App Server and Dev server VMs as it is....
However the Systems team is saying they can't give access to AD from new VMs. They say it will cause issue to actual Prod servers.
But how can we access SharePoint with having connectivity to AD.
Kindly let know what needs to be done for keeping access to AD without hampering Live servers. Thank you

Comment: Cloning existing is possible but I think not supported. The only way to have cloned farm is to 1. Build new one , 2.Install custom solutions (if any) 3. Attach content DBs to replicate content. This approach is not ensuring that your cloned farm will have same configuration. Recently we have been using SPDocKit for that, it can create an XML file for autoSpInstaller so farm are closely aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to clone a farm as you have done is to take a copy of all required servers and deploy this to an entirely separate network. This includes AD servers etc. required to run the farm. Attempting to run a clone farm as you have currently taken it on the same network as your production farm will cause you all sorts of issues.

There is a supported way to create another farm with the same settings as your production farm - see [https://technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff627859(v=office.14).aspx) for details on the steps required. Using this procedure, you create a new farm with a configuration database only, then create a settings-only backup from your production farm and restore this to the second farm. You will also need to copy the content databases form your production farm to the second farm and attach them to the content web applications. There are some simple instructions for this part at [https://sharepointzee.wordpress.com](https://sharepointzee.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/how-to-move-your-sharepoint-2010-database-to-a-test-farm-with-a-different-url/).

You can also use another method to create another farm with the same settings - build a new farm (ideally using PowerShell) taking the service application and content databases from the source farm to the new farm a part of the build process. When creating a service application for example, if you specify the name of a database that already exists on the SQL Server used for the farm that is the correct type (and suitable version), this database will be used for the service application and therefore all settings and data that are included in the database will effectively be migrated to the new farm for the service application you've just created. Obviously your new farm will have to be either the same patch level or newer than the source farm. This latter method requires more knowledge of SharePoint, but is likely to generate you a more suitable farm for your organisation.